# android sqlite query statement for specific date result

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, sum

i want to query for total amount from pro_price for this year.. is there anything wrong here in the sqlite query statement getDate().endWith(getThisYear())?

```
 public double SumPriceYear(){

Cursor sum = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM( " + Pro_Price + " ) FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " Where " + Pro_Date + " = '" + getDate().endsWith(getThisYear()) + "' ", null);
if(sum.moveToFirst())
{
    return sum.getDouble(0);
}

return sum.getDouble(0);
```

}

Comment: What is the format of the values in the Pro_Date column?

Answer (score 0):

Your select sum should have a column name with it not a value. Also, you should not compare a date to just a year.  It wont match.  You need to compare year to year.

Try This:

```
public double SumPriceYear(){

Cursor sum = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(COLUMN_NAME) FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE date(" + Pro_Date + ",'%Y') = '" + getDate().endsWith(getThisYear()) + "' ", null);
if(sum.moveToFirst())
{
    return sum.getDouble(0);
}

    return sum.getDouble(0);
}
```

I made changes to:

- SUM(COLUMN_NAME)
- WHERE date(" + Pro_Date + ",'%Y')